# Get min price for an item grouped by name

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a list of offers of different products from different stores, i like to set a show=1 where the product has the lowest price from all stores.

my DB structure is like this

```
        "ID" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"db_name_ID_seq"'::regclass) ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
        link text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        link_short text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        query text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        warehouse text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        categoria text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        current_price double precision,
        min_price double precision,
        coupon text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        coupon2 text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        from_bot text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        flag text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        flag_link text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        show smallint,
        link_original text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        CONSTRAINT db_name_pkey PRIMARY KEY (link)
```

i have tried some different solutions but i can get just one product per name to be flagged to show=1

```
    cur = conn.cursor()
    #cur.execute("Select LINK, MIN(CURRENT_PRICE), WAREHOUSE  from db_name GROUP BY LINK,NAME,WAREHOUSE".format(db_name_scrap_temp))
    cur.execute("SELECT mt.link,mt.current_price,mt.warehouse FROM db_name mt INNER JOIN(SELECT name, MIN(current_price) minprice FROM db_name GROUP BY name) t ON mt.name = t.name AND mt.CURRENT_PRICE = t.minprice".format(db_name_scrap_temp,db_name_scrap_temp))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:

        db_link = row[0]
        db_current_price = row[1]
        db_warehouse = row[2]
        cur.execute("LOCK TABLE db_name;"
                    "UPDATE db_name SET SHOW = 1 WHERE LINK = '{}' AND CURRENT_PRICE = {}".format(db_name_scrap_temp,db_name_scrap_temp,db_link,db_current_price))
    conn.commit()
```

what i need is to list unic items, regardles os the link (store) with the min price.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` to get the lowest price per product.  Note that the ORDER BY clause is required for the DISTINCT ON clause.  Also, you should think about what to do if there's a tie in price.  As written, this query will return one of the options, but you can't really predict which one.  Add to the order by clause to improve the logic:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name)
  link,
  current_price,
  warehouse
FROM db_name
ORDER BY name, current_price ASC;
```

You don't need a loop either:

```
WITH lowest_price_ids AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (name)
    id,
    link,
    current_price,
    warehouse
  FROM db_name
  ORDER BY name, current_price ASC)
, update_show AS (
  UPDATE db_name set show = 1 WHERE EXISTS (
    select FROM db_name where db_name.id = lowest_price_ids.id
   )
)
UPDATE db_name set show = 0 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  select FROM db_name where db_name.id = lowest_price_ids.id
);
```

Comment: thanks, i think this will work, you second quary is missing a ) somewhere i'm traying to figure it out... as i get an error -- ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «)»
LINE 17: );

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,
 (case row_number() over(partition by name order by price)
 when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as  show
from products
```